# Ошибка установки пакета NuGEt,

Tags: c#, nuget

Описание
Не удалось найти пакет "Rocket.API 5.0.0.694" в следующих первичных источниках: "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json". Убедитесь, что все интернет-источники пакетов доступны (ЛИБО) что идентификатор и версия пакета указаны правильно.

На другом девайсе всё работало.
net framework 4.8 (latest)
библиотека классов .net framework 4.8
[image: источник указан верно]
[image: пакет, вроде бы, доступен]

Comment: что в консоли студии?

Comment: Не удалось найти пакет "Rocket.API 5.0.0.694" в следующих первичных источниках: "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json". Убедитесь, что все интернет-источники пакетов доступны (ЛИБО) что идентификатор и версия пакета указаны правильно.
Это и сесть текст консоли

Comment: с другими пакетами такой проблемы нет?

Comment: есть. Ни один не устанавливается. Даже vpn Не помог. Хотя, на ноутбуке такой проблемы нет, сеть одинаковая.
На пк, где проблема, полностью переустановил visual studio. Не помогло...

Comment: операционка какая?

Comment: windows 11. pro

Comment: Тогда действительно странно, должно всё работать. Быть может фаервол или антивирус какой мешает.

Comment: Пробовал отключать антивирус. Kaspersky TS. Не помогло
Насчет файерволла не уверен. Что мне попробовать сделать?

Comment: если необходимо, мы можем решить этот вопрос через звонок. Вы будете руководить, я - пытаться чинить.

Comment: Покажите что там за package source mapping настройки и что там в общих настроено, отредактируйте вопрос